# How to stop TeXForm from making powers look like composition

Tags: latex

If I do `TeXForm[(Log[x])^2]` the result is `\log ^2(x)`, but in my world $\log^2(x) = \log(\log(x))$. How do I get TeXForm to render it as `(\log(x))^2`?

Edit: Some have suggested using `HoldForm`. Doing `TeXForm[HoldForm[(Log[x])^2]]` still gives `\log ^2(x)`.

Comment: Wrap just the `Log[2]` in `HoldForm`

Comment: Up to http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NestedLogarithm.html , the common notation for the nested logarithm is $\log_n(x)$ or $\log_{(n)}(x)$. The notation $\log^n(x)$ to this end is not standard.

Comment: The command TeXForm[HoldForm[(Log[x])]^2] performs \log (x)^2.

Comment: The problem here is the `HoldForm` - it does not do what it should do, i.e. to hold exactly the same form as input. `HoldForm[(1 + 2)]` gives `1+2` but it should give `(1+2)`. As long as they are not going to fix the `HoldForm` functioning your only solution is to do it "manually".

Comment: I suggest using `Log->log` before TeXForm. That is, for example, use 'Log[x]^2+y^3/.Log->log//TeXForm` to get what you want.

Comment: @Somos: No, he/she does not want `\log (x)^2` but instead `(\log (x))^2`.

Comment: @azerbajdzan Yes, you are correct. More extreme measures are required.